# Remove trailing 0's in a 5 decimal place price

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have a site where the currency has been set to 5 decimal places because they price small items individually, such as £0.00023

but some products are more, such as £1.45, but the price is being displayed to the user as £1.45000 - how can I strip the last 0's off but only to 2 decimal places - so if a price is £1.00, it still leaves at least 2 0's.

In the price.phtml, the following line displays price, but I need to somehow strip the 0's..

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730180/format-price-in-the-current-locale-and-currency

I always use the following to format price

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

Comment: Thanks bob but this still shows the price with 5 decimals, is there a way I can strip off all the trailing 0's except the 2 after the decimal point, so

£0.50000 becomes £0.50 ??

Comment: what is being stored to $_finalPrice, also are you doing this within price template file or outside of price template?

Comment: the actual value of $_finalPrice is 0.5 and I'm doing this from within the price.phtml albeit in a custom theme so not amending any core templates

Comment: what about if you try $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, false, false);

Comment: ah oh wait might of confused things, the line of code I pasted above is slightly wrong, its $_regularPrice not $_finalPrice

If I use your query in message above, $_regularPrice still returns 0.5

Comment: haha ok try $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_regularPrice, true, false);

Comment: returns £0.50000

Fun this isnt it :/